# SQL developer shortcut of duplicate line

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

When I'm using shortcut **ctrl+shift+D** to duplicate line, sometimes the new line will be created in the next line, but sometimes it just append in the same line. I just want to it always to be created in the new line.

Comment: When it is appended to the same line, are you highlighting the text you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it depends on your selection. If your selected line containes a new line character then duplicated line will be the new line else duplicated text will be created as a continuation of the same line:

if you select the line below (without CR)
select
result of duplication will be
**select**select
if there is a new line char at the end of your line and
your selection captures it too
**select**

then the result will be
**select**
select

Regards...

Comment: thanks, finally I know the reason of this weird action.

Comment: Yoou are wellcome....